# Add character to end of nth line in terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm trying to add a number of spaces to the end of the **N**:th line of a file from the command line.

Can anyone show me how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean "every nth line"? or just "line number n"?

Comment: @glennjackman every nth line

Answer (score 5):

If you mean "line number N", use sed:

```
n=5
sed -i "${n} s/$/    /" file
```

If you mean "every nth line", use awk:

```
awk -v "n=$n" 'NR % n == 0 {$0 = $0 "    "} {print}' file > file.new
```

or perl

```
perl -i -pe '$. % '"$n"' == 0 && $_ .= "    "' file
```

Comment: Sorry - tried using awk, now getting the error: invalid -v option
Any ideas?
@glenn

Comment: What is your OS and version of awk?